# Error: The integer literal 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF can't be represented exactly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, encryption, aes

I am trying to use AES encryption to encrypt and store my data to firebase my algo for the same is

1. take user input
2. encrypt
3. store to firebase
   and for decryption
4. fetch data from firebase
5. decrypt
6. use decrypted data
   for this purpose I am using following code

code to send data to encrypt:

```
 List<String> dataTOEncrypt = [name.text,contact.text,Bus_Type.text,Bus.text,Driver.text];
                              List<dynamic> encryptedData = Encryption().encryptData(dataTOEncrypt);
                              var d = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Bus').get();
                              var id = d.docs.length+1;
                              await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Bus').doc('$id').set({
                                'image':imageUri??"",
                                'bus_name':encryptedData[0],
                                'bus_contact':encryptedData[1],
                                'bus_type':encryptedData[2],
                                'bus_number':encryptedData[3],
                                'driver':encryptedData[4]
                              });
```

My encryption class code

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
final key = Key.fromLength(64);
final iv = IV.fromLength(32);
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
class Encryption {
  encryptData(List<String> data) {
    List<dynamic> encryptedList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(data[i], iv: iv);
      encryptedList.add(encrypted);
    }
    return encryptedList;
  }
}
class Decryption{
  decryptData(List<dynamic> data){
    List<String> decryptedList =[];
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(data[i], iv: iv);
      decryptedList.add(decrypted);
    }
    return decryptedList;
  }
}
```

but this thing is giving me the following errors:

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: /D:/software/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pointycastle-3.1.3/lib/key_derivators/argon2.dart:42:27:
Error: The integer literal 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF can't be represented exactly in JavaScript.
  static const int M32L = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/dashboard/components/Add_Trip.dart:715:37:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'bus_name':encryptedData[0]??"",
                                    ^
lib/screens/dashboard/components/Add_Trip.dart:716:40:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'bus_contact':encryptedData[1]??"",
                                       ^
lib/screens/dashboard/components/Add_Trip.dart:717:37:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'bus_type':encryptedData[2]??"",
                                    ^
lib/screens/dashboard/components/Add_Trip.dart:718:39:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'bus_number':encryptedData[3]??"",
                                      ^
lib/screens/dashboard/components/Add_Trip.dart:719:35:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver':encryptedData[4]??""
                                  ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Add_Bus.dart:462:55:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                              'bus_name':encryptedData[0]??"",
                                                      ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Add_Bus.dart:463:58:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                              'bus_contact':encryptedData[1]??"",
                                                         ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Add_Bus.dart:464:55:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                              'bus_type':encryptedData[2]??"",
                                                      ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Add_Bus.dart:465:57:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                              'bus_number':encryptedData[3]??"",
                                                        ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Add_Bus.dart:466:53:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                              'driver':encryptedData[4]??"",
                                                    ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Add_Driver.dart:282:40:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_name':encryptedData[0]??"",
                                       ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Add_Driver.dart:283:43:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_contact':encryptedData[1]??"",
                                          ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Add_Driver.dart:284:38:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_id':encryptedData[2]??"",
                                     ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Add_Driver.dart:285:43:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_address':encryptedData[3]??"",
                                          ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:258:49:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                        'bus_name':encryptedData[0]??"",
                                                ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:259:52:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                        'bus_contact':encryptedData[1]??"",
                                                   ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:260:49:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                        'bus_type':encryptedData[2]??"",
                                                ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:261:51:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                        'bus_number':encryptedData[3]??"",
                                                  ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:262:47:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                        'driver':encryptedData[4]??"",
                                              ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:451:53:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                            'bus_name':encryptedData[0]??"",
                                                    ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:452:56:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                            'bus_contact':encryptedData[1]??"",
                                                       ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:453:53:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                            'bus_type':encryptedData[2]??"",
                                                    ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:454:55:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                            'bus_number':encryptedData[3]??"",
                                                      ^
lib/screens/Bus%20Screen/Edit_Bus.dart:455:51:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                            'driver':encryptedData[4]??"",
                                                  ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Edit_Driver.dart:248:40:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_name':encryptedData[0]??"",
                                       ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Edit_Driver.dart:249:43:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_contact':encryptedData[1]??"",
                                          ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Edit_Driver.dart:250:38:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_id':encryptedData[2]??"",
                                     ^
lib/screens/Drivers/Edit_Driver.dart:251:43:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
            'driver_address':encryptedData[3]??"",
                                          ^
/D:/software/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pointycastle-3.1.3/lib/src/utils.dart:313:9:
Error: The integer literal 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF can't be represented exactly in JavaScript.
      ((0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) ^ ((1 << (64 - count)) - 1));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/software/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pointycastle-3.1.3/lib/src/platform_check/platform_check.dart:6:35:
Error: Method not found: 'getPlatform'.
  static Platform get instance => getPlatform();
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

I got that javascript can store the max value to 2^53-1.
I think I can store the data to firebase by simply converting it to base64 value or to String value but that thing causes error in decryption.

Comment: can your code use BigInt ? that's not a library, that's a (relatively) new native in javascript `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFn`

Comment: didn't worked already tried

Comment: In what way did it not work? Perhaps you tried incorrectly - oh, you're relying on other peoples libraries. hmm, that's not easy to fix then

Comment: I used it like this ```BigInt.parse(encryptedData[0])``` while storing to firebase

Comment: under code to send part I have tried that

Comment: Not sure what a BigInt.parse is - but since `BigInt(0xffffffffffff) != 0xffffffffffffn` you're already fighting a losing battle that way

Comment: ```'bus_name':BigInt.parse(encryptedData[0]),```  this is the exact way I haev done ....parse is the method to change the existing datatype to BigInt

Comment: Again, I was referring to the javascript native [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) which has no such method - and again, converting Number to BigInt at that stage it's already too late, the precision has been lost

Comment: I am bit cofused and didn't get exactly what should I do

Comment: can you elaborate it more according to my code

Comment: No, your code doesn't use BigInt, so I can't elaborate more